# Nodal Analysis Help

Tags: circuit-analysis

Please see attached image. Please can you check why my nodal analysis of for node 'x' is incorrect (according to solutions)

Also could please explain to me how one gets from the second line to third line in the solutions.

Thanks

[image: Question]
[image: My attempt]
[image: Solutions]

Comment: Well, Vx is the sum of the currents going through Rp multiplied by Rp. And we know Vout=A0(Vplus - Vminus) hence Vout=-A0*Vminus. After that it's just algebra.

Comment: why is it the sum of current going through Rp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see with the way you set up your problem is the right hand side. It should be a negative, but I'll set it up for you:

$$ \frac{V_1-V_x}{R_2}+\frac{V_2-V_x}{R_1}+\frac{0-V_x}{R_p}+\frac{V_{out}-V_x}{R_f}=0$$

By the previous equation (Kirchhoff's law) you are saying that all the currents that go into that node add up to zero. By your convention, you are saying that the currents that go into the node are positive, that's why the fractions have a positive sign in front of them. One way to keep track, at least I would do it, is to set up your equation on one side of the equal sign that why you won't mess up the signs (the summation of all currents add up to zero). You could assume all your currents are going into the node and by your convention those are positive. That's what I did.

Breaking up the previous fractions you get:
$$\frac{V_1}{R_2}+\frac{V_2}{R_1}+\frac{V_{out}}{R_f}-\frac{V_x}{R_2}-\frac{V_x}{R_1}-\frac{V_x}{R_p}-\frac{V_x}{R_f}=0$$
Now all you have to do is collect \$V_x\$ terms and solve for \$V_x\$
$$\frac{V_1}{R_2}+\frac{V_2}{R_1}+\frac{V_{out}}{R_f}-V_x\bigg(\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_p}+\frac{1}{R_f}\bigg)=0$$

From there, you can isolate \$V_x\$
$$ V_x=\bigg(\frac{V_1}{R_2}+\frac{V_2}{R_1}+\frac{V_{out}}{R_f}\bigg)\cdot\frac{1}{\bigg(\frac{1}{R_2}+\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_p}+\frac{1}{R_f}\bigg)}$$

We've arrived to the final solution you have there. If you look that last term in the right hand side (the inverse of the inverse sum) is the same as finding the parallel equivalent of \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$R_p\$, and \$R_f\$, which is the way the final solution is expressed.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to include the effects of Rp is to consider the Thevenin equivalent of the circuit at the left of **X** (including Rp). You will end up with a single source and a single resistance which is easy to analyze.

Comment: Can you please show me how to use Thevenin in this instant; I genereally try to avoid thevenin and norton equivalents as I find it a bit tricky to follow.

Comment: Thevenin equivalents are very powerful to get insight into circuits. Try to use them!

The Thevenin equivalent consists in R_th and V_th. To find R_th you can set your generators to 0 and compute the equivalent resistance: Rp//R1//R2. To find V_th you can apply superposition: set V2=0 and find the open-circuit voltage V_th1=(Rp//R1)/(R2+Rp//R1) (a voltage divider). Then set V1=0 and find the V_th2=(Rp//R2)/(R1+Rp//R2). The sum of both terms gives V_th=V_th1+Vth2

Comment: Oh wow. Could you please clarify witha diagram or so on how the superposition works and also how the final circuit equivalent will look for Thevnin and Norton